# assigning has_many through extra fields on join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

Models:

```
class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deals, through: :deal_items
end

class DealItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu_item
  belongs_to :deal

  # has table column "primary"
end

class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :menu_items, through: :deal_items
end
```

controller:

```
def create
  @deal = Deal.new(deal_params)

  params[:menu_items].each do |id|
    menu_item = MenuItem.find(id)
    @deal.menu_items << menu_item
    # the primary field on the DealItem object never got assigned!
  end

  if @deal.save
    render :index
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

How do I assign the `primary` column's value either before or after the MenuItem is associated with the deal?

Comment: may I know which primary fields are you talking about?

Comment: `primary` is an attribute on the DealItems model.

Comment: better use a `after_save` callback on DealItem model and assign primary values on there

Comment: there's no way to assign value of the parameter through a callback.  I can't pass value to the callback so it has no way of knowing what value to assign it.

Comment: `@deal.deal_items.create!(primary: '')` did you try this ? In controller

Comment: Is there a reason not to use #accepts_nested_attributes_for http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html